# Can I stay up late tonight? ('up' is adjective or adverb?)

Tags: parts-of-speech

> Can I stay up late tonight?

We say, "Stay cool, Stay calm, Stay silent".

After 'stay' come adjectives.

What's the part of speech in case of 'stay up late' like in the sentence above?

Comment: compare: go to bed early.

Comment: 'up' is hard to be defined with respect to my point of view.

Comment: it is not up; it is: be up versus be in bed or sleeping.

Comment: @Lambie in the phrase 'stay up late' there is no 'be'.

Comment: You can stay up late or be up late.

Comment: @Lambie I think in case of 'be up late', the 'up' is an adjective and vice versa ,if, according to your comment.

Comment: Yeah, well, people here have fancy names for phrases like this. And I can't be bothered to figure it out.  Where was he? He was up late. Can be adverbial as it tells us where he was.

Comment: After "stay", we can also have adverbials: "stay here", "stay in the room", "stay where you are", so your examples in "Stay cool, Stay calm, Stay silent" don't establish what the part of speech is.

Comment: In modern grammar, "up" is classified as a preposition.

Comment: It's neither.; **up** is a preposition. **To stay up** is a prepositional verb (aka a phrasal verb).  It means something like: to go to bed later than normal, or to stay awake late. [see the definition here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stay-up)

Comment: Oxford Languages defines _up_ meaning _out of bed_ as an adverb.

Comment: @KateBunting Aha, thank you.  "Are you still up"? Answer: No, I'm in bed. I didn't realize that in English a preposition can be used to describe a place where a person is. For the others, yes, like I said above. He is up or is he down? See Cambridge: adverb of place.

Comment: @KateBunting - except that it would be possible to "stay up" even if you are technically in bed. E.g. "We went to bed early, but stayed up chatting until midnight".

Comment: @BillyKerr - That sounds like a contradiction to me. I would say _sat up_ or _stayed awake_ rather than _stayed up_.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: My original answer was simply incorrect on at least two counts. Thanks to BillJ for pointing out my mistake; I've rewritten the answer to fix those errors.

Most sources consider 'stay up' to be a *phrasal verb*, a special, idiomatic construction with a meaning different from its parts. Usually, the second element in a phrasal verb is an adverb or a preposition (a word that describes how a noun relates to another word in the clause) - here, it's the preposition 'up'.

The sentence can also be understood using 'up' in its idiomatic sense as an adjective meaning awake/active:

> Can I stay awake late tonight?

Where late can be either an adverb modifying stay or an adjective modifying tonight; both interpretations have the same meaning as the idiomatic form mentioned above.

Comment: To Ryan, My dictionary says 'up' is an adverb in case of 'stay up late'.

Comment: To Ryan, My dictionary is a Asian maker.

Comment: I think English is really hard in terms of 'parts of speech'.

Comment: In modern grammar, "up" is classified as a preposition. So "stay up late" is analysed as V+Prep+adverb. Functionally, it's predicator+complement+adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ I respect your analysis which applies a rising aspect of modern grammar.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for pointing that out, you're totally right! This is especially embarrassing because I memorized a list of the prepositions and STILL messed up what kind of word 'up' is.